# How do I optimize the output for ebooks?

Tags: pdftex, compiling

In ps2pdf there is a `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` option to control the nature of the pdf output. Is there an analogous setting in pdflatex to do the same thing?

Comment: I'm curious as to the 'optimizations' that this option sets up...

Comment: I am not too sure what your definition of "optimize" is, can you please clarify? If you optimize to save you "development time" for example the easy answer is to leave the `.pdf` as is:)

Comment: Do you mean have it PDF/X or PDF/A compliant? If so, there's the [pdfx](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx) package. Alternatively there's my [jmakepdfx](http://ctan.org/pkg/jmakepdfx) application which post-processes the PDF with ghostscript.